# How to detect cast player finish playing?

Tags: java, android, chromecast, exoplayer2.x

How to detect cast when finish playing. If no forward items within `MediaQueueItem`.  disconnect chromecast device.

Detect events of a particular type of Session in `SessionManagerListener`.

```
mSessionManagerListener = new SessionManagerListener<CastSession>()
{
    @Override
    public void onSessionStarted(CastSession session, String essionId) {
    castSession.getRemoteMediaClient().queueLoad(mediaItems, 0, 0, null).setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<RemoteMediaClient.MediaChannelResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onResult(@NonNull MediaChannelResult mediaChannelResult) {
            int statusCode = mediaChannelResult.getStatus().getStatusCode();

            if (statusCode == CastStatusCodes.SUCCESS) {
                Log.e(TAG, "statusCode001 :" + statusCode);
            } else {
                Log.e(TAG, "statusCode002 :" + statusCode);
                mRouter.selectRoute(mRouter.getDefaultRoute()); // DisConnect cast
            }

        }
        });
    }
}
```

When the player plays the media.
Logcat ... statusCode001 0
When the Finish playing.
Logcat ... does not appear

Answer (score 1):

Thanks Nirel
And posting Chromecast SDK (Android) - is there is a way to check if the media played on the device is finished playing?
Your answer, Shivang

This is a working code.

```
public int mIdleReason=MediaStatus.IDLE_REASON_NONE;


mSessionManagerListener = new SessionManagerListener<CastSession>()
{
    @Override
    public void onSessionStarted(CastSession session, String sessionId)
    {
            session.getRemoteMediaClient().addListener(mRemoteMediaClientListener);
    }
};

private RemoteMediaClient.Listener mRemoteMediaClientListener = new RemoteMediaClient.Listener() 
{
    @Override
    public void onStatusUpdated()
    {
        int playerStatus = mediaStatus.getPlayerState();

        if (playerStatus == MediaStatus.PLAYER_STATE_PLAYING)
        {
            mIdleReason = MediaStatus.IDLE_REASON_FINISHED;
            Log.e(TAG, "playerStatus PLAYING");
        }
        else if (playerStatus == MediaStatus.PLAYER_STATE_BUFFERING)
        {
            mIdleReason = MediaStatus.IDLE_REASON_FINISHED;
            Log.e(TAG, "playerStatus BUFFERING");
        }
        else if(playerStatus == MediaStatus.PLAYER_STATE_IDLE && mediaStatus.getIdleReason() == MediaStatus.IDLE_REASON_FINISHED && mIdleReason == MediaStatus.IDLE_REASON_FINISHED)
        {
            Log.e(TAG, "statusCode FINISHED");
        }

    }
};
```

it works well for me.